# How to write a LINQ to dataGridView in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I've got stuck with developing a LINQ search in `dataGridView`. On the form I dragged `button`, `bindingSource` `dataGridView` and `comboBox`. When I started programming `button` I've catched the unlogical action from C#. When I write `else if` block then button doesn't work, if I write `else` block, it works. How is it possible

Seacrhing criterias:

-The most expensive item in the list

-The cheapest item in the list

- Item which presents in collection

I've connected `bindingSource` to the `dataGridView` object

Here is a code:

```
public partial class Form1: Form 
{
     public List<ProductClass> Product {get; set;}
     public Form1()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
          Product = new List<ProductClass>
          {
             new Product("BigMac", 300.0, 4000, "In collection"),
             //....... there is 19 more objects 
          };
          productBindingSource.DataSource = Product;
     }
}
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "The cheapest item")
       {
           var query = Product.OrderBy(x=>x.Price);
           var minimum = query.First(); // Taking the first element from the list 
           productBindingSource.DataSource = minimum;
       }
       // This else if block is ignored, instead of it works block else 
       else if(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "The most expensive item)
       {
           var query = Product.OrderBy(x=>x.Price);
           var maximum = query.Last(); // taking the last element from the list 
           productBindingSource.DataSource = maximum;
       }
       // This block works when I choose from comboBox or Item in Collection or The most expensive item criteria 
      else 
      {
           var query = from pr in Product where pr.CollectionStatus == "In collection" select pr;
          productBindingSource.DataSource = query;
      }
}
```

I can't find out what is wrong here :(

Also when I wrote something like that:

```
else 
{
     if(//....)
     {
         //....
     }
     else
     {
        //....
     }
}
```

It crashes me all so the LINQ doesnt work completely :(

Any help with the code template is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to set breakpoints, step through code and examine values, in this case from the ComboBox selected item.

Comment: Looks like you get results with on row but not when results is more than one row.  I normally put results into a DataTable and then use : datagridview1.DataSource = dt.

Comment: @jdweng I am not allowed to use dataTable :(

Comment: Please help!!!!!!

Comment: productBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();

Comment: comboBox1.SelectedItem is not a string. I suppose that you set that productBindingSource as the datasource of your combo. If it is so SelectedItem is a ProductClass instance. So you should use _comboBox1.SelectedItem.Name_ or whatever property you have for the DisplayMember

Answer (score 0):

One big issue is that you query the `DataSource` and then set the very same `DataSource` to the result of the query `productBindingSource.DataSource = minimum`. The first query has 20 items (you say) but then what? The query returns the minimum (or the maximum) product and then the `DataSource` has only that one product to choose from next time instead of 20.

Your plan is OK to have the `DataGridView` display the query result...

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    enum QueryType{All, Min, Max, }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        dataGridView.DataSource = DataSource;
        dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        // Format columns
        DataSource.Add(new Product("Template"));
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Product.Description)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        var priceColStyle = dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Product.Price)].DefaultCellStyle;
        priceColStyle.Format = "F2";
        priceColStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        priceColStyle.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 10, 0);
        DataSource.Clear();

        comboBox.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(QueryType)));
        comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += onCBSelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
BindingList<Product> DataSource { get; } = new BindingList<Product>();
```

BUT when you perform a query, it needs to be on some *other* collection of products and not the circular reference to the `DataSource` itself.

```
private void onCBSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSource.Clear();
    switch (Enum.Parse(typeof(QueryType), comboBox.Text))
    {
        case QueryType.All:
            foreach (var product in ProductDatabase) DataSource.Add(product);
            break;
        case QueryType.Min:
            DataSource.Add(ProductDatabase.OrderBy(_=>_.Price).First());
            break;
        case QueryType.Max:
            DataSource.Clear();
            DataSource.Add(ProductDatabase.OrderByDescending(_ => _.Price).First());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dataGridView.ClearSelection();
}
```

WHERE `ProductDatabase` is a collection of products similar to the mock database created here:

```
public Product[] ProductDatabase { get; } = new Product[]
{
    new Product ("Sponge"),
    new Product ("Kite"),
    new Product ("Card"),
    new Product ("Hat"),
    new Product ("Potato"),
    new Product ("Shoes"),
    new Product ("Cactus"),
    new Product ("Whistle"),
    new Product ("Paper"),
    new Product ("Glass"),
    new Product ("Crayon"),
    new Product ("Feather"),
    new Product ("Vegetables"),
    new Product ("Rake"),
    new Product ("Rice"),
    new Product ("Bucket"),
    new Product ("Yarn "),
    new Product ("Salt"),
    new Product ("Flowers"),
    new Product ("Flour"),
};
```

And WHERE:

```
public class Product
{
    static Random _rando = new Random(1);
    public Product(string description) => Description = description;
    public string Description { get; }
    public decimal Price { get; } = (decimal)_rando.NextDouble() * 10;
}
```

Summary, if you stop overwriting your original "database" with the query result, then subsequent queries should have no issues running.

[image: three queries]